# How can I find what tests cover specific Go code?

Tags: go, testing, visual-studio-code, code-coverage

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to see what tests cover the functions in my Go code. I'm working on a code base with other developers so I didn't write all the tests/code myself.

I see some functions that are partially covered, or almost entirely covered, but they have no references anywhere (in its own, or other packages), and the functions aren't called directly in any of the tests.

Is there a way I can find which tests are covering that specific code? When I've tried to find if it's possible, all I get are articles showing how to write/run tests and get coverage percentages/highlighting, but nothing that actually shows if it's possible at all.

For the record, I'm using VS Code on linux and running `go test ./... -cover` in my terminals, as well as `Ctrl+Shift+P -> "Go: Toggle Test Coverage In Current Package"` for coverage highlighting within VS Code.

Comment: It's easy to execute a single test with the code coverage tool turned on. I'm not sure if that's what you want, though... it sounds like you want the opposite. And that's a lot harder to do, because there's not a 1:1 relationship between code and tests (put another way: given a single line of code, it could be executed by any number of tests)

Comment: Break the code and see what test failed.

Comment: Why do you need this? It's such an unusual requirement it seems likely to be an XY Problem.

Comment: @Flimzy I had a feeling it wouldn't be a 1:1, I was just hoping there was something obvious I was missing.

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski (and @Adrian) All the tests pass, I'm just trying to find where existing tests are so I can raise the coverage. My thoughts are that if the code is covered partially somewhere, I'd want to add to what exists. I want to try avoiding having 3 or 4 locations that test the same function(s).

Comment: Tests _should_ live next to the code they test. If they don't, your code base could probably stand to be better organized. Usually `foo.go` is tested in `foo_test.go`, or `test/foo_test.go`.  Rarely, you'll see tests in an entirely different directory, but then they're probably not unit tests, and the value of calculating coverage of those is dubious at best.

Comment: @Flimzy I definitely agree. I'm trying to group them where I can, but I'm having trouble finding where tests written by others exist. It feels like a catch-22 at the moment.

Comment: If I had that task, I would probably disable _all_ tests (i.e. with a build tag that is never met), then re-enable them one-by one, moving them to the proper place as I go.

Comment: @Flimzy That's a really good idea, I hadn't thought of approaching it that way. I think I'll go through that process, if for no other reason than to understand this mess a little more.

Comment: @T1960CT: Do it in small steps! Commit early and often. If you aren't annoying your colleagues with too many pull requests, you're probably doing it wrong :)  (And don't hesitate to point out to them that if they had written the tests properly the first time, you wouldn't be cleaning up their mess now.)

Comment: @Flimzy I agree. Problem is it's someone more senior than I am who's writing the stuff I'm cleaning now. They're newer to Go, but I'll have to raise my voice about it and get out of the "conform to seniors" mentality. Thanks again for your help, I'll start the process you suggested and clean as I go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the fuller picture in view now, via comments, it seems that you have a mess of tests, written by someone(s) less experienced with Go, and your goal is to clean up the tests to follow standard Go conventions.

If I were faced with that task, my strategy would probably be to disable all tests in the repository, by using a build tag that never gets executed, such as:

```golang
// +build skip

package foo
```

Confirm that all tests are disabled, by running `go test ./... -cover`, and confirm that you have 0% coverage everywhere.

Then, test by test, I would move each test into its proper place, and put it in a new file without the `skip` build tag.

If it's a big project, I'd probably do one package at a time, or in some other small, logical steps, to avoid a monster pull request. Use your own judgement here.

I'd also strongly resist the urge to do any other cleanups or fixes simultaneously. My goal would be to make each PR a simple copy-paste, so review is trivial, and I'd save a list of other cleanups I discover, to do afterward.